# How to ignore implicit order by in psql group by query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

Postgres implicitly sorts row based on the group by column. In MySQL, we can change this behavior by setting the ORDER BY NULL. Is there any similar alternative way to achieve this in Postgres [[Reference]](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/208166/group-by-needs-order-by-null-to-avoid-filesort)?

Comment: "As we know, PSQL implicitly sorts row based on the group by column" Interesting. Who is "we"? Can you prove this? Why do you think so? Which order do you want to be applied?

Comment: Fellow stackoverflowers. I want to skip the sorting.

Comment: Postgres typically uses hashing to do the grouping there is no sort involved. Please **[edit]** your question and add the query that is giving you the problem and the execution plan. But if you don't care about the order, then what is the problem with the order that Postgres uses?

Comment: you could use `order by null::text` or `order by 42+0` or `order by random()` - but the whole question doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: The results could be sorted because of the query plan that has been executed, but there is no guarantee. For random results you need RANDOM()

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL only sorts for grouping if it thinks that that is the best way to get the job done.  It doesn't just add sorts out of neurosis; so there is no point in telling it to stop doing that.  PostgreSQL isn't a MySQL clone, don't treat it like it is one.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, there is a way to achieve this in PostgreSQL, which is the SQL language used by PSQL. In PostgreSQL, you can use the `GROUP BY` clause to group rows based on the values of one or more columns. By default, the rows in the result set are sorted based on the values of the columns specified in the `GROUP BY` clause. However, you can use the `ORDER BY NULL` clause to disable this default behavior and prevent the rows from being sorted based on the values of the `GROUP BY` columns.

Comment: PSQL is not supporting, order by null. So this approach is not working.

Comment: The sentence "*PostgreSQL, which is the SQL language used by PSQL*" makes no sense. The database product is called PostgreSQL it uses SQL as its query language. `psql` is the command line client to interact with a running PostgreSQL server.

Comment: Not true, there is no default sorting when using a group by. Check this query: SELECT g1.s, count(*)
FROM generate_series(1, 100) g1(s)
GROUP BY s;